# Updating Angular 5 to Angular 12, Do i need to change anything inside angular-cli.json file

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

My company asks us to update the angular version 5.2 to angular 12.*. I am following the angular upgrade guide process. There are lot of package we are using in our application.

Q1. Other than naming angular-cli.json to angular.json is enough or do I need to do any changes inside JSON file.

Q2. We are using lot of dependency packages, How to get to know which version will be suitable for Angular 12.

List of Packages:

1. bootstrap
2. chart.js
3. concurrently
4. copy-webpack-plugin
5. core-js
6. font-awesome
7. fullcalendar
8. jquery
9. json-server
10. moment
11. node-sass
12. primeng
13. quill
14. rxjs
15. zone.js
16. ssri

there are lot of others are there, could you let me know where can i find compatible version of these dependencies for angular 12.

Comment: Only suggestion I can give is update the angular version to 12 and update the dependencies to latest versions you can check the latest stable version on npm, you can skip rxjs, zone.js it is part of angular so it will be mostly handled automatically. once you are on latest versions, test functionality of each library, for bootstrap compatible version check npm only.

Comment: Do i need to do any configuration change on angular-cli.json other than name change

Comment: I feel your best bet is start a new application with Angular 12 (why Angular12 instead of Angular 17?) add the necessary dependencies, and copy the source files

Comment: Our application is very big, i guess it will take lot of efforts